# image upload resize php before server

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I would be extremely grateful for any help with this problem.  I have a joomla based website and using a third party extension, I am trying to enable visitors to upload information including photos.  However, I need to implement some php code to resize the image **before** uploading to the server to reduce upload times and upload failures. 
The developers of the site have place a 'resize hack' but this only resizes the image after reaching the server.

```
// Resize Params Hack
                $OriginalfileWidth = getimagesize($file);
                $NewFileWidth = 400; // Set here the new desired width

                if ($OriginalfileWidth[0] > $NewFileWidth) {
                    $this->resize($NewFileWidth, $file, $ext);
                }

            }
        }


    }

    protected function resize($newWidth, $targetFile, $ext) {

        $targetFile = JPATH_ROOT . '/' . $targetFile;

        if (empty($newWidth) || empty($targetFile)) {
            return false;
        }

        switch ($ext) {
            case 'jpg':
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFile);
            break;
            case 'gif':
            $src = ImageCreateFromGif($targetFile);
            break;
            case 'png':
            $src = ImageCreateFrompng($targetFile);
            break;
        }

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($targetFile);
        $newHeight = ($height / $width) * $newWidth;
        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
        if (file_exists($targetFile)) {
            unlink($targetFile);
        }

        switch ($ext) {
            case 'jpg':
            imagejpeg($tmp, $targetFile, 85); // 85 is my choice, make it between 0 – 100 for output image quality with 100 being the most luxurious
            break;
            case 'gif':
            imagegif($tmp, $targetFile);
            break;
            case 'png':
            imagepng($tmp, $targetFile, 8);
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

I have noted code on searching stackoverflow, but I simply do not know how to input it.
Many thanks for your help.
Matthew

Comment: PHP is a server-side language (it's only executed on the server side). You can't do any resizing with PHP "before" the image hits the server. Look for a JS solution. But please, it's 2013, stay away from flash.

Answer (score 0):

Use swfupload:

http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

A demo on how to resize here:

http://demo.swfupload.org/v250beta3/resizedemo/index.php

This resizes the image first before you upload it using flash.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize image before upload to server, you have to use canvas. I am using following code. I would helpful to you.

HTML

```
<input id="imageFile" type="file"><input type="button" value="Resize Image"  onclick="ResizeImage()"/> 
<img src="" id="image_output">
```

Javascript

```
function ResizeImage() {
    var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('imageFile').files;
    var file = filesToUpload[0];

    // Create an image
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    // Create a file reader
    var reader = new FileReader();
    // Set the image once loaded into file reader
    reader.onload = function(e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 400;
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;

            if (width > height) {
                if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                    width = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } else {
                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

            var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.getElementById('image_output').src = dataurl;
        }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```